# url subdomain wildcard redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I read some of the answers related to the topic but my situation is a little different. I'm hosted on GoDaddy shared Linux hosting. Currently my application is setup to handle uri's as follows:

`https://state.domain.com/region/client/xyz/function1`

I want to change the application so the new url will be as follows. The change has been implemented and working for new clients but for my existing clients I want to this to be seamless without having them to update the url they are using to access the application. The new url would be:

`https://country.domain.com/state/region/client/xyz/function1`

We have quite a few clients that are using the application and I was wondering if we can use wildcards to create generic redirection. What would be the best way to achieve this? 
I was reading subdomain redirection through htaccess but in my case I need the generic redirection to give me the complete uri so for example in the above case the redirected uri should be exactly as specified above. In another case if the incoming request is for

`.../region/client/xyz/function2`

It should be redirected to

`.../state/region/client/xyz/function2`

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: How do you know what country someone is trying to access based on the old URL?

Comment: or, if using the old url, is the country always "usa" or something?

Comment: yes correct its based on the old url. The country is always us for the existing customers that we want to redirect